# WhoID and WhatId is null when send email

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks

I have created a **trigger on task** (before Insert) and just displaying the **trigger.new** value ,i.e, the task which is created .
In the debug it is showing me that **whoid** and **whatId** is null but I am sending the email from "Send An Email" button on the activity history of contacts .

Here is the code for the trigger :-

```
trigger triggerOnTask on Task (before insert) {
    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert){
        for(task ts : trigger.new){ 
            System.debug('>>>>>>ts'+ts);
            System.debug('>>>>>>'+ts.Description);
            System.debug('>>>>>>'+ts.whoId);
            Id myId=ts.whoId;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code **whoId** is null in debug when I click on send Email button.

Any suggestions why is the **WhoId** and **whatId** are null in the task created.

Also , this is working in my dev org and I'am getting the whoid but in sandbox it is working on leads but not working on the Contacts.

Comment: Can you please add your code.

Comment: @MSCB, above is the code I have written on task.

Comment: Your requirement does not make sense to me.

Comment: @MSCB , what is not understandable in the above process

Comment: Could there be another trigger on task creation that's interfering with this? Maybe blanking out the whoId?

Comment: @mkorman , no their is no other trigger which is present on the Task.